# How to make an MDB consume sequentially in WildFly

Tags: jms, ejb, wildfly

I'm following [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/ejb-message-driven-beans) to create a JMS message listener. Everything run correctly. When a producer sends a message the listener can recognize the new message and start doing something.

However, when the producer publishes multiple messages at the same time, the listener also handles these messages concurrently. How can I make the listener run sequentially? I want it to handle the next message only when the previous message is handled successfully.
This my my `MessageListener`:

```java
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "SendingSMSQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class SendgridEmail2SmsMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            log.info("Receive {}", message);
            // Do some heavy things          
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            log.info("Finish");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Listen message sending SMS failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research, I found that there is an ActivationConfigProperty that allow us define the maximum sessions can handle our request, so in my case, I just need to set maxSession is 1 like this:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "SendingSMSQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1")
})
public class SendgridEmail2SmsMessageListener implements MessageListener {
```

For more information, let reference this page https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Message_Driven_Beans.html